# I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 4964): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@b13d73

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am very new to flutter and I am making a login and register authentication using firebase. 
I completed all the steps from setting up the app in firebase to adding all the required dependencies and all that.
 Below are the files.
**project level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app level build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}


def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "co.amanchaudhary.flash_chat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
}
```

And here is the error in the console,
In the beginning the I/BiChannelGoogleApi was shown, whereas now, the two others are also shown in the console.

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 4964): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@b13d73
W/DynamiteModule( 4964): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth( 4964): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

I am calling, when registered button is clicked,

```
            ButtonStyle(
              buttonColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              buttonText: "Register",
              onPressedButton: () async{
                try {
                final  newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
                  if(newUser !=null){
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                  }
                } catch (e) {

                  print(e);
                }
              },
            ),
```

This exception occurs when clicking the register button,
[image]

Comment: That's not an error message, that's in informational message.  You can tell because of the letter "I" in front.  If something isn't working the way you expect, your question should explain what that behavior is.

Comment: but it is not going to the chatscreen after the register button is clicked, what might be the reason?

Comment: I suggest adding some logging and update your question with your debugging information.

Comment: the app simply stops responding after register button is clicked, and gives the exception. Please have a look to my updated question.